# my app working fine on online but not working on offline help me

Tags: android, gridview, android-sqlite

I want to make my application offline .When I am inserting data from url to database it works fine when internet available but my app not show any thing in gridview when no internet available what is wrong in my app please help me why gridview not loading data from database help me

```
               public class MainActivity extends Activity {
CategoryListAdapter3 cla;
static ArrayList<String> Category_ID = new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<String> Category_name = new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<String> Category_image = new ArrayList<String>();
String URL, URL2;
String SelectMenuAPI;
String _response;
String status;
GridView gridview;
private DbHelper mHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase dataBase;
private boolean isUpdate;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       mHelper=new DbHelper(this);

        dataBase=mHelper.getWritableDatabase();


    gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    cla = new CategoryListAdapter3(MainActivity.this);
    new TheTask().execute();

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent iMenuList = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    Subcategory.class);

            iMenuList.putExtra("Category_ID", Category_ID.get(position));
            iMenuList.putExtra("Category_name", Category_name.get(position));

            startActivity(iMenuList);

        }
    });

}

void clearData() {
    Category_ID.clear();
    Category_name.clear();
    Category_image.clear();

}

public class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

SelectMenuAPI = "http://www.fff/mobile_api.php?response=getmaincategories";

        clearData();
        URL = SelectMenuAPI;
        URL2 = URL.replace(" ", "%20");

        try {

            Log.i("url", "" + URL2);
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(URL2);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
            _response = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return _response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        try {

            JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject(result);

            status = json2.getString("Status");
            if (status.equals("1")) {

                JSONArray school2 = json2.getJSONArray("data");
                //
                for (int i = 0; i < school2.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = school2.getJSONObject(i);





                    String id = object.getString("category_id");
                    String name =object.getString("name");
                    String  image_path = object.getString("image_path");






                    dataBase=mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();

                    values.put(DbHelper.KEY_MYID,id);

                    values.put(DbHelper.KEY_FNAME,name);
                    values.put(DbHelper.KEY_LNAME,image_path );

                    System.out.println("");
                    if(isUpdate)
                    {    
                        //update database with new data 
                dataBase.update(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, values, DbHelper.KEY_ID+"="+id, null);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //insert data into database
                        dataBase.insert(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
                    }
                    //close database
                    dataBase.close();


                }

            }

            else {





            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        displayData();


    }
}





private void displayData() {
    dataBase = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor mCursor = dataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "
            + DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null);
 //
 //     Category_ID.clear();
 //     Category_name.clear();
 //     Category_image.clear();
    if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

   Category_ID.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_ID)));

    Category_name.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_FNAME)));

       Category_image.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_LNAME)));

        } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
    }
    gridview.setAdapter(cla);

    mCursor.close();
}





               public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
static String DATABASE_NAME="userdata";
public static final String TABLE_NAME="user";
public static final String KEY_FNAME="fname";
public static final String KEY_LNAME="lname";
public static final String KEY_ID="id";

public static final String KEY_MYID="myid";


public DbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" ("+KEY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY  
             KEY,"+KEY_MYID+" TEXT, "+KEY_FNAME+" TEXT, "+KEY_LNAME+" BLOB)";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);

}

}











     public class CategoryListAdapter3 extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;


private AQuery androidAQuery;


public CategoryListAdapter3(Activity act) {
    this.activity = act;
//  imageLoader = new ImageLoader(act);
}

public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return MainActivity.Category_ID.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ViewHolder holder;
    androidAQuery = new AQuery(getcontext());
    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewitem2, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


    holder.txtText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title2);
    holder.imgThumb = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image2);

    holder.txtText.setText(MainActivity.Category_name.get(position));

        a 
   ndroidAQuery.id(holder.imgThumb).image(MainActivity.Category_image.get(position), true,  
     true);

    return convertView;
}
private Activity getcontext() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtText;
    ImageView imgThumb;
}
```

}

Comment: to request data from url you need internet connection

Comment: I am unable to see from the code which items CategoryListAdapter3 uses and where you give it an array.

Comment: yes first time i used internet and get alldata insert in database when second time i close internet my app not get data form database app show blank

Comment: Where is the code to show data at second time?

Comment: i update class of  CategoryListAdapter3 but problem not here my app work foine when internet available problem is its not show data offline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have called displayData() only in onPostExecute, so the data is displayed in grid only when you receive data from that URL.

Solution: Call the displayData() once in onCreate function before new TheTask().execute(). So now data  will be displayed from the DB if available and then fetch from that URL using HTTPClient. If no internet then the data will still be displayed.

Note: Make sure the cursor size greater than 0 inside displayData(), else display no data text instead of grid view.

happy coding :)

Comment: how do i call displayData()  in oncreate bcoz i already calll  TheTask().execute() so duplicate function wil call please modify my code what u say im confuse

Comment: Bcoz onPostExecute will not be called as @umair.ali said. Alternative: Check if internet connection is available or not.. if net connection available call task().execute() else call displayData(). `public static boolean isConnection(Context con) {
  ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) con
    .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
  if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
    && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
    && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
   return true;
  } else {
   return false;
  }
 }`

Answer (score 1):

check internet Availability  before web service call:

```
public static boolean isInternetAvailable(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)  context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: is work now but my database show duplicate data how to restrick dataabse to show unique data only

Answer (score 0):

This is quite obvious, You are actually calling you `displayData()` in `postExecute`, but in case of no internet, exception will occur you `doInBackgroud` and null will be passed to `postExecute`...Exception again in `postExecute` and your `displayData()` will not be called.

So first, implement checks for null values to avoid exceptions, and then close try closing you db in catch block.

Comment: displayData is outside of try/catch in onPostExecute

Comment: i did but its also not help

Comment: Can you provide stacktrace of exception while executing in no-internet enviroment...??